# MATLAB: Undefined function 'libsvmwrite' for input arguments of type 'char'

Tags: matlab, csv, octave, libsvm, mex

I'm trying to convert a CSV file to LIBSVM/SVMlight format. I found the following code to do it:

```
SPECTF = csvread('SPECTF.train'); % read a csv file
labels = SPECTF(:, 1); % labels from the 1st column
features = SPECTF(:, 2:end); 
features_sparse = sparse(features); % features must be in a sparse matrix
libsvmwrite('SPECTFlibsvm.train', labels, features_sparse);
```

I used it on Octave on a specific file, and it worked properly. 
However, when trying it on MATLAB, I received the error:

```
Undefined function 'libsvmwrite' for input arguments of type 'char'.
```

Neither "labels" nor "features_sparse" are chars... (they are doubles). Where is my error? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first argument for `libsvmwrite` is of type char ( the filename 'SPECTFlibsvm.train'). I think the problem is on the error message given by Matlab. The error message says that the function doesn't exist for input of type char, but most likely it should be that it doesn't exist at all (the message could maybe make sense if Matlab was designed as an OPP language).

Anyway, you simply don't have the `libsvmwrite` function in your path, or you somehow messed up the installation of the libsvm interface.

Comment: Thank you @carandraug, you were right: I was accidentally using the .mex files of 'libsvmwrite' created on a windows XP OS, while running it on a Windows 7 OS... ;)

Answer (score 0):

Probably you loaded only the source code, which is written in c. You need to compile it. Go to the `matlab` directory of libsvm and read the instructions.